# Python - Displaying json data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api

I am trying to write my first API query with python. I am calling an extremely simple dataset. (http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json). This displays information about the number of people in space.

I can return the number, but I want to try and  display the names. So far I have:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")

data = response.json()

print(data["number"])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate by `data['people']` and then get the name:

```
for people in data['people']:
    print(people['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get names or crafts just do this:

```
print("Fist name: ",data["people"][0]["name"])
print("Fist craft: ",data["people"][0]["craft"])
```

Eventually you can put it in a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(data["people"])):
       print(data["people"][i]["name"])
```